# Pass additional parameters to OData end point in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: routes, odata, endpoint, url-parameters

I need to pass additional parameters to an OData endpoint with ASP.NET Core.

When coding it like this

```
public class RequestDtoController : ODataController
{
    // ...

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet]
    //[ODataRoute("GetRequests(userID={userID}, showByAuthor={showByAuthor})")]
    public IQueryable<DocumentRequestDTO> GetRequests([FromODataUri] string userID,
                                                      [FromODataUri] bool showByAuthor)
    {
        // code 
    }
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
https://localhost:12345/TestServer/RequestDto/GetRequests(userID='0388',showByAuthor=False)
    ?$count=true&$orderby=TimeStamp%20desc&$skip=0&$top=26
```

the endpoint doesn't even get called.

I cannot seem to be able to specify "ODataRoute" in the controller; This is only present in ASP.NET and not in ASP.NET core.

How do I need to specify/code this to make this work please?

I did look for answers here, but they require "ODataRoute".

With the answer below, I changed my code like this:

```
public class RequestDtoController : ODataController
{
    // ...

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("GetRequests(userID={userID}, showByAuthor={showByAuthor})")]
    public IQueryable<DocumentRequestDTO> GetRequests([FromODataUri] string userID,
                                                      [FromODataUri] bool showByAuthor)
    {
        // code 
    }
}
```

My adjusted query looks like this:

```
https://localhost:12345/TestServer/RequestDto/
GetRequests(userID='0388',showByAuthor=False)
?$count=true&$orderby=TimeStamp%20desc&$skip=0&$top=26
```

However, GetRequests() doesn't even get called that way.

Comment: working with OData not only controller itself can be significant part, Setup part and EDM model also can be important. 
If possible, could you provide part of the whole project that can be used?
perfect, if it would be git repo that can be checked out

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET core the route can be specified in `HttpGet`

```
public class RequestDtoController : ODataController
{
    // ...

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("GetRequests(userID={userID},showByAuthor={showByAuthor})")]
    //[HttpGet("GetRequests({userID},{showByAuthor})")]
    public IQueryable<DocumentRequestDTO> GetRequests([FromODataUri] string userID,
                                                      [FromODataUri] bool showByAuthor)
    {
        // code 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is accepted by the compiler, but doesn't seem to work for me. I added new info to my question to reflect this, as I cannot seem to post my adjusted query in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

/RequestDto/GetRequests(userID='0388',showByAuthor=false) works for me without issue when I don't capitalize the `F` in `false`.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RequestDtoController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("GetRequests(userID={userID},showByAuthor={showByAuthor})")]
    public IQueryable<DocumentRequestDTO> GetRequests(
        [FromODataUri] string userID,
        [FromODataUri] bool showByAuthor)
    {
        return new List<DocumentRequestDTO>().AsQueryable();
        // code 
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```